# How to get external URLs likes

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm trying to get the list of all the pages that a user "likes", both Facebook pages and external pages.

I know that the facebook pages (such as http://www.facebook.com/DealExtremeFans) I can obtain them with the "me/likes" value from the Graph.

But for a page such as (http://mashable.com/2012/01/20/advertisers-this-is-what-an-nfl-fan-looks-like-infographic/) that has a like button (under the title) I don't see how to get those likes.

Is this possible? If not, are you planning on adding support for this any time soon?

Thanks

EDIT:

According to the response below, even though they are added via the "like" button they are really "Shares".
Now my question is, how do I get those shares? what's the graph for them? I tried "me/shares" but doesn't exist. 
Is there a way?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, but it looks like that URL only has shares:

[Click here](https://graph.facebook.com/http://mashable.com/2012/01/20/advertisers-this-is-what-an-nfl-fan-looks-like-infographic/).

And here is a [link to a tutorial for getting the data via jQuery](http://www.mattcashatt.com/post/index/Obtaining-and-Parsing-Open-Social-Graph-Data-with-JSONP-and-jQuery).

Comment: That's strange, since the button says "Like", and it says that me and 38 persons like that and the FB graph says 39 shares. Now, how do I get those shares? I tried "me/shares" but it returns an error. What's the path for these?